# Get Data For Java Script Code

Tags: asp.net

I have a piece of code in javascript which calculates something ,

There is a label in asp.net application , How can I get the value of it from javascript ?

here is i have tried :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>JASP</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x = document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML;
            alert(x);
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="My Text"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Parkhid - You may have an issue with this code because you're trying to get a value out of your element before the DOM has finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
```

**Update:**

Create a function, place your code inside that and call it where appropriate. Ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayText() {
        var x = document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
        alert(x);
    }
</script>
```

Now call the function `displayText()`, where required.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your rendered source code you will see that the `Label` has been converted into a HTML `span` tag, and that the `ID` has also been re-rendered to ensure it is unique.

Therefore, you can use the `ClientID` property to find out what the rendered `ID` will be:

```
var x = document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using the code below:

```
var value = document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML
```

Note:  You ideally just want the text and not the HTML, but if you have to support versions of Internet Explorer prior to 9, then you will need to use a combination of `textContent` and `innerText`.